# EntityFramework 5 is required but EntityFramework is installed.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need assistance in trying to figure this out.

I tried adding a new MVCController to my project that has MVC and WebApi, and I kept getting an error. After reading a number posts, I checked that I don't have configSource in webconfig, uninstalled EntityFramework, installed EntityFramework and MVCScaffolding. Now when I try and add a MVC controller I noticed that the use async Controller actions is greyed out and it is stating that I need to ensure that I have EntityFramework 5 ir greater - although I have it installed. [image]

Now I'm getting the following error stating that I don't have EntityFramework higher than version 6, although you can see at the back that EntityFramework 6.1.3 is already installed.

[image]

Comment: is it installed in the correct project? is there a reference to EntityFramework.dll? are those versions the same?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, yes, yes and yes. See the above screenshots, where the packetmanager is stating that it is installed. My only option that is available is to uninstall - which I have done and re-installed it.

Comment: What version of VS is this? Looks like 2010.

Comment: No it's 2015. I've had to slowly rebuild the project from scratch. This was very annoying, and time consuming.